# PHP strtotime() returns false for JavaScript Date string

Tags: php, javascript, date, strtotime

At browser,in JS

```
var today = new Date()
todaySendToServer = today.toString();
```

I am sending todaySendToServer to server in AJAX call or as part of URL.

At server, in PHP:

```
$todayJsDateString1 = preg_replace('#^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s([\d:]+)\s([a-zA-z]{0,2})$#','$3-    $2-$1 $4 $5', $todayJsDateString); 
$todayTimestamp = strtotime(todayJsDateString1);
```

The strtotime() PHP call returns false for date strings returned by some browser(like IE9)

Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you format your string according to a standard? for example ISO8601

Comment: How to format JavaScript Date string to ISO8601? Is there any API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the timestamp instead, so you even don't need to use `strtotime` in the php side.

```
var today = new Date();
var ts = today.getTime() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple typo I guess, you missed a dollar sign:

```
$todayJsDateString1 = preg_replace('#^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s([\d:]+)\s([a-zA-z]{0,2})$#','$3-    $2-$1 $4 $5', $todayJsDateString); 
$todayTimestamp = strtotime($todayJsDateString1);
```

Comment: It didn't work for JS date string sent from IE9 browser. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why not send it as a timestamp all the way?

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

$todayTimestamp = $todayJsDateString;
```